# Proof Verification: a primitive root modulo $p^n$ is also a primitive root modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I'd like some advice on my approach for this exercise, which has been giving me some hesitancy. Let $\alpha$ be a primitive root modulo $p^n$. Show that $\alpha$ is also a primitive root modulo $p$, where $p$ is an odd prime. (Note that the odd prime distinction is made since $2$ needs to be treated different than the rest of the primes.) Here's what I have.

Since $\alpha$ is a primitive root modulo $p^n$, $\alpha^{\varphi(p^n)}\equiv1\pmod{p^n}$. It is evident $\varphi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}=p^n\cdot(1-1/p)=p^n\cdot\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p^n}{p}\right)\cdot(p-1)=p^{n-1}\cdot(p-1)$.
Now, $\alpha^{p^{n-1}\cdot(p-1)}\equiv1\pmod{p^n}$. Observe that a primitive root modulo $p$, $x$, implies $x^{\varphi(p)}=x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$. Since $p^{n-1}\cdot(p-1)$ is a multiple of $p-1$, we conclude $\alpha$ is also a primitive root modulo $p$.   $Q.E.D.$

My only concern is the final step. I don't feel simply claiming $p^{n-1}\cdot(p-1)$ is a multiple of $p-1$ is a strong enough justification between modulo $p^n$ and modulo $p$. Am I just overthinking this proof or is there something I can adjust?

Comment: Adding to @ArturoMagidin's comment: note that your proof as written would apply to *any* integer $\alpha$ that isn't a multiple of $p$, regardless of whether it's a primitive root modulo $p^n$.

Comment: You can class all values mod $p^n$ into mod $p$, and the only values that hit all non-zero values mod $p$ can touch all those classifications...

Comment: I didn't know that LaTeX command, thanks. Our textbook specifically laid out the intermediate step; I was just trying to follow through. Crap, I totally forgot about the "smallest positive integer" bit. Thanks!

Comment: Your wish is granted.

Answer (score 2):

We must show that the powers of $\alpha$ cover all residue classes $\bmod p$ that are coprime to $p$ ( this is equivalent to showing $\alpha$ generates the multiplicative group $\bmod p$, or that $\alpha$ is a primtive root $\bmod p$).

So take $a$ coprime to $p$, since $\alpha$ is a primitive root $\bmod p^n$ and $\gcd(a,p^n)=1$ there is $k$ such that $\alpha^k \equiv a \bmod p^n$, it follows $\alpha^k \equiv a \bmod p$ as desired.